# 'deny from all' in htaccess is denying to add files even in php files

Tags: php, .htaccess

We have includes folder which contains our css,js and some .inc files. We want to restrict direct access to it So we applied the following rule in .htaccess

```
deny from all
```

What I understood from this is, it restricts the direct access to them while allowing the files to include in other php files. But it is restricting us to include them in other php files.
Is there anything wrong?

Comment: What does the include PHP code look like? And what are the file system paths for the .htaccess, the PHP file, and the include folder?

Comment: My .inc files contains just some <script> and <link> tags with locations in same folder. Eg : Project -> includes
This includes folder contains files.inc,dependencies. I am including the js and css in dependencies folder to .inc and using these .inc outside. includes folder contains .htaccess.

Comment: If this line in `/includes/.htaccess` then only content inside `/includes/` will be blocked not outside one

Comment: I am expecting that with above .htaccess I must be able to include those .inc files in my main php files and direct access to those .inc and dependencies folder (which is sub folder for includes) is restricted.

Comment: I think you question doesn't have enough information. Using `include` in PHP doesn't go through htaccess at all. Show small sample of your PHP code and folder structure.

Comment: I have the following structure
Project/includes/dependencies (this contains js and css)
Project/includes/myfile.inc (this .inc file contains script and link statements)
Project/scripts
Project/main.php

What I want to do is 
1) Restrict direct access to includes and its sub folders.
2) Restrict direct access to scripts folder. 
3) But, must be able to include the .inc file in main.php file
4) Also, files in scripts must not be allowed to directly called from browser address bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `allow` there as well to let the local include requests pass through.

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

<script src="X"> and <link = "Y"> tags will not work if user doesn't have access to X or Y. Because css and scripts are for your site's users, not for you. The only solution if you do not want users to recieve you site's css/js files is to include them inside html page like this

```
 <script>
    <?php  $fh = fopen("./content/script.js", "r");
            while (! feof($fh)) :
            print fgetss($fh, 2048);
            fclose($fh);
     ?>
 </script>
```

And the same with CSS. But it is very weird to hidefrom clients files that were made for them anyway. You'd better store .inc files in special folder just for them.